# Is a pointer just a key-value pair?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is a pointer just a key-value pair? For example:

```
int n = 3;
int *p = &n;
p; // <0x...>
&p; // 3
```

Seems analogous to (in JavaScript):

```
var o = {}; // the memory on the computer
var p = '<0xfoo>'; // a key, an address, in the memory
var n = 3;
var o[p] = n; // create a key-value pair in memory
p; // '<0xfoo>';
o.p; // 3 <== dereference
```

Is this analogy useful or is it missing something big?

Comment: Based on the comments in your post `&p` should be `*p`.

Comment: That's a bad analogy. JavaScript has no pointer concept at all.

Comment: If you had to pick something in javascript, it's probably closest to a limited version of `eval` as in `var n = 3; var p = "n"; eval(p);`.

Comment: @texasbruce, it is a type, not just a value, no? And the dereference operator is a built-in operation on that type, just like you can multiple ints but not chars.

Comment: @texasbruce: I'd say it's closer to being just a key, though of course it can also be a value.

Comment: @ggundersen C++ types do not necessarily travel with the value itself. A pointer is (on an x64 machine) 8 bytes pointing to a physical memory location. The "key" you think exists it the value of this memory location. The value is whatever is stored there.

Comment: A pointer *is* bytes? My understanding is that it is a variable that stores an address. Something else--nothing in the C++ language--actually takes that value and uses it as a key to find the value in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better analogy is all of memory is a giant array and a pointer is an index into the giant array. Every element of the giant array is 1 byte (actually `sizeof(char)`). If `char *` was the only pointer you used, than this analogy would be near perfect.

address-of `&` is the index of an element in the giant array.

dereference `*` is an element in the giant array at some index.

The complication is that different pointer types group consecutive elements together. For example `int *` is 4 bytes big, so it expects to have 4 consecutive elements in the giant array.

For example, if `int *intptr` has the index of `0x1000`, then it assumes it using the elements at `0x1000`, `0x1001`, `0x1002`, and `0x1003` to hold the value of the int.

`sizeof` returns the number of elements a type will need. For example, `sizeof(char)` is 1 and `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Comment: I prefer your analogy too. And my reason for analogizing at all was to better reason about what happens when pointers change. *If* they can be understood, at least at some level of abstraction, as either keys to an object or indices to an array, then it is a clear leap to say that if you change the key/index, you change the value you will get back. Is that fair?

Comment: @ggundersen yes, pointers can be a hard to conceptualize. Thinking of pointers as an indexes will prepare you for pointer arithmetic and multi-level indirection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the analogy is useful. A pointer can point to anything, including memory areas where it must not point to, which results in undefined behaviour. Consider this:

```
int *ptr = new int(123);
delete ptr;
// ptr no longer points to anything accessible,
// dereferencing it would yield undefined behaviour
```

Or this:

```
int *f()
{
  int i = 123;
  return &i;
}

int *ptr = f();
// ptr no longer points to anything accessible,
// dereferencing it would yield undefined behaviour
```

Or this:

```
struct S {};
S s;
int *ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&s);
// bad cast, dereferencing ptr would yield undefined behaviour
```

So, as you can see, having a "key" (the pointer) does not mean there is any valid "value" (the pointee) at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you actually have is not getting paradigm right. I can see you are trying to break into the world of the C programming language with experience in higher level programming. The first question is why C? What does people typically do with C?

To get to your question more directly, C is a (only) language good at direct manipulation of memory and memory mapped address. You need to have basic understanding of computer architecture in mind when programming in c (where are things allocated, or even what does allocation mean etc). A pointer here basically is a word long value to hold an address, type of the pointer give you some clue what's being held in that address. So I would suggest refrain from making a connection of key-value pair with pointers, it's not the right 'paradigm'.

Historically people use C to do a lot more things of higher level, but those task are gradually shifted to higher level languages with better expression power and of course worse performance. Looking into C nowadays means breaking into the black box and find out what's inside, it takes more than just making language feature connections. To truly understand C you will need to prepare yourself some knowledge in computer architecture and surrounding o/s concept, then think in those "language" instead of higher level concepts.

Comment: Right, but the machine takes a pointer's value and uses it as a key to look-up what is stored at the address. The mechanics of that look-up process is a black box, even to the C programmer. He or she just tells the machine to find the value stored at that address. I don't see how this isn't analogous, conceptually, to any other kind of key-value look-up. I don't think this is just a language feature connection.

Comment: It's not black box at all on this level. The *p is pretty much telling the compiler to move data in certain address to the register. All syntax you see there make more sense when you consider how to actually compile them into assembly

Answer (score 1):

In a strange kind of way, it is... however you must think of it as operating on an array rather than any kind of sparse container, and this array is the *entire addressable memory* in the computer.

Then, the 'key' is the memory address that you can use to lookup a byte! Its very simple really, but it gives people difficulty because they try to understand it in abstract terms.

Memory is a vast block of bytes, and a pointer is the number of one of them.

Now what gets complicated is when you define the bytes that pointer is addressing as something other than a byte. You can say "this pointer points to a string, or a struct' and then you have to mentally convert the bytes that the pointer addresses as something else. For a string, this is easy - the byte the pointer addresses is the first character in the string, and each subsequent byte is the next character. The pointer still only addresses the first character (ie the first byte) though, its up to you (or your compiler) to handle the rest of the bytes as some more complex construct.

So in C, lets say you have a string, say "Hello", and you have a pointer to the first byte, you can take your pointer, add 3 to it and replace the byte at that new address with 'Z' and your string will then read 'HeZlo'. You've addresses the 3rd byte in the string simply by adding 3 to the pointer. However - here's a pit to trip you, if you added to your pointer, it now points at the address 3 bytes along, not the original, so your string would read 'Zlo' because you 'moved' the pointer. And its for this reason people tend to treat pointers as a more opaque type, so it makes it conceptually easier not to screw with them and cause problems like I just described.

In time, language writers abstracted them further, so we have smart pointers and references and fancy containers like your javascript... but these are all wrappers around raw pointers and memory.

Ps. one other thing to understand. You have to store the pointer data somewhere, and its usually in program data .. so a pointer is a variable, and as variables are just bytes in memory, so you can have a pointer to a pointer, and you can modify the pointed-to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a slight difference in the code examples but I can see a variable being assigned to an object acts almost like a pointer in that its a "reference" type and not quite a key-value pair.

For example in JavaScript,

```
// Part 1:
var o = { foo: 'bar' };
var b = o;               // b acts like a pointer
b.foo = 'baz';
console.log(o.foo);      // will give you 'baz'

// Part 2:
// if you wanted you can reference another object with b now
b = {};
b.foo = 'bar';
console.log(o.foo);      // will still give you 'baz'
```

In the C example,

```
int n = 3;
int m = 4;
int* p = &n;

printf('%d', *p);        // will give you 3 (the value of n)

// Part 1:
*p = 5;
printf('%d', n);         // will give you 5, because it acts like the b variable in the JavaScript example and "acts" on the memory address of n

// Part 2:
*p = &m;
*p = 10;
printf('%d', n);         // will still give you 5 because the reference of the pointer has changed like the second part of the JavaScript example
```